# How to correctly define a one-to-many relationship in Entity Framework models?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two entities in database: customer and user and building a one-to-many relationship between them, so 1 customer -> many users.

This is my customer model:

```
public class Customer
{           
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

What would be the correct User model, I mean with Customer property and CustomerId property or just CustomerId? So this:

```
public class User
{       
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Customer Customer { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Customer")]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
}
```

.. or this?:

```
public class User
{       
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Customer")]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You can read about relations [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships)

Comment: The question is opinion based because there is no single "correct" way to represent one-to-many relationships. In addition to the shown models there could be also a model w/o collection navigation property, w/o explicit FK property and other combinations.

Comment: Just because several options are available doesn’t make it an opinion based question, since the advantages and disadvantages of the different variants can clearly be explained. (Either you can navigate or you cannot.)

Answer (score 2):

Actually it should be like the code example below. You should specify what is local primary key, remote key and if there is navigation property (`Customer`), then You should specify "How should it recognize the object" => based on the this or that key of Customer (`CustomerId`).

```
public class User
{       
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //other properties

    [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
}
```

If You are not interested in having navigation property, You can simply avoid that to have only:

```
public class User
{       
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //other properties

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
}
```

> More info can be found there: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx

---

Note: You do not need to specify `[ForeignKey]` attribute, if You are using `Navigation Property` with the same name (e.g. `Customer` & `CustomerId`).

If there are multiple references to the same class (e.g. You have User that will have exactly 2 Customers (CustomerA, CustomerB), then You must specify following:

```
public class User
{       
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //other properties


    [ForeignKey("CustomerIdA")]
    public Customer CustomerA { get; set; }
    public int CustomerIdA { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CustomerIdB")]
    public Customer CustomerB { get; set; }
    public int CustomerIdB { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you have a correctly set navigational property between User and Customer. In the second case, you cannot navigate from User to Customer, and you have a `Foreign Key` attribute that point to a non-existent property.

You should, however, invert the order of the `ForeingKeyAttribute` to make it clearer (both ways are OK, though):

```
[ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
public Customer Customer { get; set; }

public int CustomerId { get; set; }
```

If you won't need `User.Customer`, you can skip setting up the navigational property altogether. The same applies to `Customer.Users`, you can skip setting up that navigational property if it's not needed.